# Excel VBA compare cells in a Column on one sheet with cells in a Column in another sheet, if matched copy row

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen several similar questions but none that quite fit the bill for what I am trying to accomplish.

I am working on a training matrix that is automated for the ease of our training coordinators. Where I am stuck at is I have a column which lists out the certifications a particular person needs (Sheet "ALL Courses Required") and I am trying to have that reference another sheet ("Cert Matrix") where all certifications are in column A and their requirements are listed out in the row beside them. All certifications have a varied number of requirements from 1 item to 20 items.

I want it to look at each cell with data in column E (Cert Numbers) on the "ALL Courses Required" Tab and look for its match in Column A on the Cert Matrix Tab. When it finds the match, I want it to look over one cell in the row and copy that cell through to the end of the requirements list. Then I want the information to be pasted in Column G (Cert Requirements) on the "ALL Courses Required" Tab, one line after another without breaks. I have a message box pop up at the end to tell the training coordinator it is done so they wont sit there and keep clicking while the macro is running.

Below is where I am at so far, the last if statement where I am actually having the search occur followed by the copy and paste is where i think my issue is. I am not getting any errors, it just isn't working.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim NeededCerts As Range
Dim SearchCerts As Range

Set NeededCerts = Worksheets("ALL Courses Required").Range("E27", Worksheets("ALL Courses Required").Range("E27")).End(xlDown)
Set SearchCerts = Worksheets("Cert_Matrix2").Range("A1", Worksheets("Cert_Matrix2").Range("A1")).End(xlDown)

For Each Cell In NeededCerts

   If Worksheets("ALL Courses Required").Range("G2") = "" Then
       Set PasteCell = Worksheets("ALL Courses Required").Range("G2")
   Else
       Set PasteCell = Worksheets("ALL Courses Required").Range("G1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
   End If
   
   If NeededCerts.Cells.Value = SearchCerts.Cells.Value Then
       SearchCerts.Cells.Offset(0, 1).End(xlRight).Copy
       PasteCell.Paste
   End If

Next Cell

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the `Cells`: `NeededCerts.Value = SearchCerts.Value`, `SearchCerts.Offset(...)`.

Comment: If i remove that part of the code it no longer is telling it to search for a match to then pull the data i need?